# Handling differences between objects inheriting from an interface

Tags: c#

I have 2 objects that inherit from an interface i created which worked nicely.  The Objects are injected into another object calls the methods of both the object.  The methods of the objects perform some simple XML manipulation which is then returned to the worker object.

I now have a change request which affects one object that inherits from the interface but not the other and I'm at a loss as to how I should handle this. I've created a couple of new methods and I simply throw a not implemented exception if its not used.  This doesn't seem "Best Practice" to me.  What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interface doesn't "need" to be fully implemented... Even in .NET there are classes that implement partially an interface (and that throw `NotSupportedException()` when used in an "illegal" way)... For example arrays are `IList<>` that don't support `Add()` or `Remove()`...

Or the `Stream` abstract class, that has an additional "pattern": `CanRead`, `CanWrite`, `CanSeek`, ..., so there are methods, and properties that tell if it is legal to use those methods.

Another way is to use an additional interface, and try casting it with [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator. The Entity Framework for example "returns" `IQueryable<T>`, that "are" `IEnumerable<T>`... But those objects even support the `IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>` interface... but not all the `IQueryable<T>` are `IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>`. You have to do a cast and see if the interface is present or not.

Answer (score 4):

I think that this is a situation where the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) comes in place.

If you find yourself having two objects for which it does not make sense to expose the same set of public members, then probably they should not implement the same interface. Or at least *not only* the same interface. You have two options here, depending on your application's logic:

1. Leave the original interface as is, and the first class (the one not needing extra methods) unmodified. Define a new interface only for the new methods, and make the second class implement both interfaces.
2. Define a new interface that inherits from the old one and contains the new methods. Leave your first class unmodified, and have your second class implement the new interface.

Implementing an interface and doing nothing more than throwing an exception in some methods is indeed a bad practice, as it breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: ok but how would i handle that in my code?  One of the interfaces will have the new method and the other wont.  Would you suggest doing an "AS" to qualify?

Comment: If you only need the simpler interface, you can pass an object from extended interface, because of inheritance and the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: @Konamiman i tried what you stated above but i get a compile error stating that the interface does not contain the new method.  The error line is in the worker object which is calling the method

Comment: It is difficult to elaborate further without seeing your code, but I guess that you either have the two objects in different variables (and then each variable should be declared as being of the type of each interface), or they are both in any kind of collection (and then you could do an "AS" checking as you suggested).

Comment: @Konamiman im passing the interface into a method in the client code like Update(IWorkspaceDirectoryItem item), but now i have 2 interfaces IWorkspaceDirectoryItem  and IWorkspaceDirectoryItemExtended. IWorkspaceDirectoryItemExtended inherits from IWorkspaceDirectoryItem

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the interface like this:

```
public interface SimpleInterface 
{
    void SimpleMethod();
    void OtherMethod();
}

public interface ExpandedInterface : SimpleInterface
{
    void ExpandedMethod();
    void OtherExpandedMethod();
}
```

That way you could declare, on your client code, if you really need an expanded interface implementer (in which case you should pass only an instance of the subset of concrete classes that implement `ExpandedInterface`) or it is enough to use a `SimpleInterface` implementer (in which case you can pass either).

The situation you presented  (needing to add funcion to one object, but not other) has more to do with the client code than the interface implementers themselves. You have to think: "in this client class, what do I *really* need: an instance of `SimpleInterface`, or an instance of `ExtendedInterface`?"

Comment: How do i handle the method calls though?  If i call a method in the client code that doesnt exist it will error

Comment: You got to the point: "If I call a method in the client code". If your client code calls `someObject.ExpandedMethod()`, it _necessarily_ means you need an object implementing `ExpandedInterface`. Your simpler objects implementing `SimpleInterface` cannot be used here. Thus, you have to either "upgrade" the objects to the ExpandedInterface _and implement methods complying to the interface contract_, or not to use the objects at all. As already said, putting "dummy" methods which raise exceptions or do nothing is Coding Horror.